# spring boot external config with sensitive information not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to load an external yml file into my spring boot app
On my classpath, I have 3 yml files for dev prod and tls profiles.

What I intend to do is to load an external file with the name "secret.yml" to override the values on the application-{profiles}.yml file.

This "secret.yml" file contains sensetive information. It will be add to gitignore file.

After some tries, I founded that spring not override the values inside the classpath only if I change the name to application-{profiles}.yml and not secret.yml

I tried to add `spring.config.name=secret` but that not working for me.

```
./mvnw -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./secret.yml -Dspring.config.name=secret.yml
```

Have you any solution for that issue ?

[UPDATE]

I do export environment variable `export secret="secret.yml"`
and then pass the variable to my command line

```
./mvnw -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./secret -Dspring.config.name=secret
```

Nothing changed

Comment: I'm not sure your relative `file:` URLs are valid. Is there a particular reason you're not using environment variables?

Comment: The url are valid because when I rename the file name to application-profile it's work and it override the content. I agree with you thar environment is best solution but I am trying to accomplish this by external files also

Comment: Is the `secret.yml` in the classpath or at the current directory (as you intended here).

Comment: I used file: so it's not on the classpath. But to make sure, I copied the secret.yml inside the classpath (under ressources) and I changed my command line to -Dspring.config.location=classpath:secret.yml and dosen't override the value

Comment: @chrylis -on strike I have an update on my question and trying to accomplish that with env variables but nothing changed

Comment: It's your file actually named `secret.yml`? Just for testing purposes to exclude possible causes of error use a standard name like `application.yml`. I have an example where I use ` --spring.config.additional-location=file:/opt/aws.yml` and works.

Comment: @mihaiB. yes the actual name is secret.yml. with application as a name it's work. but what I want is to use another name like "secret" as mentioned on the docs "If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name ". but that not working for me.

Comment: That's right, each env. needs it's own settings, I have been in same situation and struggled with the problem that my initial file name was `aws.prod.yml` and for dev was `aws.dev.yml`. My app is deployed with Docker, and when I copy the files in the `Dockerfile` I rename it to `aws.yml`. Idem for dev env: `cp ./aws.dev.yml /opt/aws.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All propsitions here works if I wrap my command line to jvmArguments.

```
./mvnw  -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./secrets.yml"
```

Thank you for all your reply

Answer (score 1):

if you pass multiple config file, take care the `order`, the last one will be override to previous config sequentially.

```
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:application-1.yaml,classpath:application-2.yaml .. other config
```

the value of `application-2.yaml` will be override into `application-1.yaml` if they have same config.

**That will be merged for different config.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a absolute path as on spring boot [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar):

`java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=application --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/secret`

If you don't know the absolute path you can find it with `pwd` command.